# Jupyterlab trying to replicate Jupiter Shift+Tab+Tab hotkey

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Trying to replicate the Jupyter Shift+Tab+Tab key combination - sticky help in Jupyterlab (top).
In Jupyterlab it's always just the small window (bottom).
  How to do similar thing in lab?

[image: Jupyter]

[image: Jupyterlab]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the question mark:

```
pd.pivot?
```

This gives you the full text without the scroll handle:

[image]

Comment: thanks, is there any easier way? IT seems very cumbersome to always type in the things +'?'

Comment: Why is typing `?` more cumbersome than typing `<TAB>`?

Comment: edited OP, it's a hotkey combination, so e.g. I would type in 'pd.pivot(' and after it hold down SHIFT while pressing TAB twice

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+I bring up Contextual Help, and you can bring it do a side window. It will always show for the current function you are in, fantastic :O
[image]